# 301 редирект для главной страницы на страницу со слэшем на php?

Tags: php

Очень нужно сделать переадресацию средствами php для главной страницы сайта, доступа к htaccess нет. Код тестирую на сервере.
Чтобы с главной страницы сайта http://wwww.test.ru без слэша на конце шла переадресация на ту же самую главную страницу сайта со слэшем на конце http://wwww.test.ru/
Есть такой код (см. ниже), но возникает циклическая переадресация, как от нее избавится, и сделать добавление слэша для главной страницы на php?

```html
<?php
$url2 = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

$request = explode('?', $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI], 2);

if (preg_match('/[^\/]$/', $request[0])) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header('Location: https://www.test.ru' . $request[0] . '/' . (isset($request[1]) ? '?' . $request[1] : ''));
    exit();
}

if($url2=='https://www.test.ru')
{
if (preg_match('/[^\/]$/', $request[0])) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header('Location: https://www.test.ru' . '/');
    exit();
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Поменяйте местами проверки, у вас если последний не слеш, то первый exit не даст дойти до второго условия

Comment: И проверяйте на 302 редиректе, иначе нужно браузер перезапускать/очищать при каждом изменении